Unpack values from column, which consist of list of dictionaries
I have dataframe, which looks like this:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"item_id": [1, 2, 3],
                   "item_properties":[
                                        [{"property_id" : 1,
                                        "property_name": "name_1",
                                        "property_value": ['property_value_1']},
                                        {"property_id" : 2,
                                        "property_name": "name_2",
                                        "property_value": ['property_value_1']},
                                        ],
                                        [{"property_id" : 1,
                                        "property_name": "name_1",
                                        "property_value": ['property_value_1']},
                                        {"property_id" : 2,
                                        "property_name": "name_2",
                                        "property_value": ['property_value_1', 'property_value_2']},
                                        ],
                                        [{"property_id" : 1,
                                        "property_name": "name_1",
                                        "property_value": ['property_value_1', 'property_value_2']},
                                        {"property_id" : 2,
                                        "property_name": "name_2",
                                        "property_value": ['property_value_1', 'property_value_2']},
                                        ],
                                ]
                   })

I need to extract values from every dictionary in column item_properties, if property_id equals to 2.
If there's more, than one element, they need to be separated by ;.
My desired df should look like this:



item_id
desired_column




1
property_value_1


2
property_value_1;property_value_2


3
property_value_1;property_value_2



What I did:
df['desired_value'] = ''
for i in range(len(df)):
    [df['desired_value'][i]] = [d.get("property_value") for d in df['item_properties'][i] if d['property_id'] == 2]
df['desired_value'] = [';'.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['desired_value']]

But pandas gives me this message:
FutureWarning: ChainedAssignmentError: behaviour will change in pandas 3.0!
You are setting values through chained assignment. Currently this works in certain cases, but when using Copy-on-Write (which will become the default behaviour in pandas 3.0) this will never work to update the original DataFrame or Series, because the intermediate object on which we are setting values will behave as a copy.
A typical example is when you are setting values in a column of a DataFrame, like:

df["col"][row_indexer] = value

Use df.loc[row_indexer, "col"] = values instead, to perform the assignment in a single step and ensure this keeps updating the original df.

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

What is right way to do it?

One way to do it if your item_properties is "ordered and well behaved":
df['desired_column'] = df['item_properties'].str[1].str['property_value']

Output:
                         desired_column  
0                    [property_value_1]  
1  [property_value_1, property_value_2]  
2  [property_value_1, property_value_2] 


This relies on the constraint that the property_id: 2 should always be second in the list.

Yes, hence the comment 'ordered and well behaved'.

You can first explode the item_properties column and from that column (which is a json) create a dataframe using json_normalize and then concat "item_id" column followed by filtering on property_id
t = df.explode("item_properties")
out = pd.concat([t[["item_id"]].reset_index(drop=True), 
                 pd.json_normalize(t["item_properties"])], axis=1)
out = out[out["property_id"].eq(2)]
print(out)

   item_id  property_id property_name                        property_value
1        1            2        name_2                    [property_value_1]
3        2            2        name_2  [property_value_1, property_value_2]
5        3            2        name_2  [property_value_1, property_value_2]

